How do I center text and img in li?
How do I place the text in the center, same line as img?
It's currently like this:

But I want it like this:



.list,
.list-div {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block!important;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.list-div li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.list-div {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-div img {
  width: 25px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
<div class="list-div">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="png-address" alt="product-safe-payment-icon" width="35" /> Dostawa nawet w 24h</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="png-address" width="35" /> Najwyższa jakość</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="png-address" width="35" /> Gwarancja zadowolenia</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="png-address" width="35" /> Bezpieczne płatności</li>
  </ul>
</div>



If I try padding or margin and target img it applies to the whole li so that's not what Im trying to achieve

Does this answer your question? Vertically align text next to an image?

Basically there is different ways for doing just that. The easiest way is to use the flex property.
Display flex by default is direction row.
align items moves items along the y-axis if we think it as a cardinal system the justify content moves it along the x-axis.
However if you change the direction to column these two also change.


.list{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}
.list-inline-item {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 gap: 5px;
}
<div class="list-div">
  <ul class="list">
<li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_png_800/czNmcy1wcml2YXRlL3Jhd3BpeGVsX2ltYWdlcy93ZWJzaXRlX2NvbnRlbnQvam9iNjgwLTE2Ni1wLWwxZGJ1cTN2LnBuZw.png" alt="product-safe-payment-icon" width="35" /> Dostawa nawet w 24h</li>
<li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_png_800/czNmcy1wcml2YXRlL3Jhd3BpeGVsX2ltYWdlcy93ZWJzaXRlX2NvbnRlbnQvam9iNjgwLTE2Ni1wLWwxZGJ1cTN2LnBuZw.png" width="35" /> Najwyższa jakość</li>
<li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon" src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_png_800/czNmcy1wcml2YXRlL3Jhd3BpeGVsX2ltYWdlcy93ZWJzaXRlX2NvbnRlbnQvam9iNjgwLTE2Ni1wLWwxZGJ1cTN2LnBuZw.png" width="35" /> Gwarancja zadowolenia</li>
<li class="list-inline-item badge-box"><img class="product-safe-payment-icon"   src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_png_800/czNmcy1wcml2YXRlL3Jhd3BpeGVsX2ltYWdlcy93ZWJzaXRlX2NvbnRlbnQvam9iNjgwLTE2Ni1wLWwxZGJ1cTN2LnBuZw.png" width="35" /> Bezpieczne płatności</li>
  </ul>
</div>




Yeah but in that case it's not in line but one above another

If you want them two by two you can use display grid also, let me update the answer with a display grid as well.
So basically the parent ul with a class of list, is dividing the space with 2 equal parts with 1 frame per each since there are 4 elements it will be two on two as in the pic.
